# How do I check two collections for equality ignoring case?

Tags: java, collections

I want to treat lowercase and uppercase values the same, and make sure two collections are equal (does not have to be sorted)

This is my implementation:

```
private boolean stringCollectionEqualsIgnoreCase(Collection<String> c1, Collection<String> c2)
{
    Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<>();
    c1.forEach(i -> s1.add(i.toLowerCase()));

    Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<>();
    c2.forEach(i -> s2.add(i.toLowerCase()));

    return s1.size() == s2.size() && s2.containsAll(s1);
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Or is it better to have my own method

Comment: That will treat `Arrays.asList( "a" )` as equal to `Arrays.asList( "a", "a" )`, is that what you want?

Comment: @OpenSauce that's fine. Before I pass in the collection I have `Set<String> uniqueStrings = new HashSet<>(strings);`

Comment: in that case, what you're doing should be fine. The `equals` method for `AbstractSet` does basically the same thing. In fact you could change your last line to `s1.equals(s2)`.

Comment: You way is fine.

Comment: @davidxxx I was going to write up an answer but it basically would have been equivalent to the answer you posted and then deleted. Perhaps you could undelete your answer.

Comment: @StuartMarks, so, equivalent to my answer? :)

Comment: @MickMnemonic Conceptually yes, but davidxxx's has more details about the exact code that would need to be written.

Comment: @Stuart Marks undeleted. It didn't sound an efficient solution in terms of performance. So I preferred to remove. What do you think about that ?

Comment: I understood from OP's comment above that they are working with a `Set` to begin with, so the whole utility method an copying of elements seemed redundant; they could just use `TreeMap`s from the start.

Comment: @davidxxx Assuming the OP is not concerned with ordering or duplicates, the code in the question is reasonable and will probably work *most* of the time. But note that the last line (which is equivalent to `s1.equals(s2)`) uses `equals()` to compare the lower-cased strings. This is subtly different from `String.equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your actual solution is very acceptable. It is clear enough and it should have a overall good performance.

You should use `Set.equals()` instead of `Set.containsAll()`. It makes the same things but it spare you from comparing the size as optimization.

1) A stream version of your code could be  :

```
private boolean stringCollectionEqualsIgnoreCase(Collection<String> c1, Collection<String> c2) {
    return c1.stream()
             .map(String::toLowerCase)
             .collect(toSet())
             .equals(c2.stream()
                       .map(String::toLowerCase)
                       .collect(toSet()));
}
```

2) Here is a second alternative with `Treeset`.
I am not sure that it is easier but it avoids explicit loops and makes the logic more explicit as factored out :

```
private boolean stringCollectionEqualsIgnoreCase(Collection<String> c1, Collection<String> c2)
{
    Comparator<String> comp = Comparator.comparing(String::toLowerCase);
    Set<String> s1 = new TreeSet<>(comp);
    Set<String> s2 = new TreeSet<>(comp);
    s1.addAll(c1);
    s2.addAll(c2);
    return s1.equals(s2);
}
```

Note that it removes duplicates according to the comparator. That means that it sorts.  So it could be slower or faster than your actual solution according to the cases. Of course for small `Set`s to compare, it doesn't matter.

Comment: +1 for the `TreeSet` approach using `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`. This comparator matches `String.compareToIgnoreCase()` which, when it returns zero, should be consistent with `String.equalsIgnoreCase()`. Note that the semantics provided here are somewhat different from the code posted in the question, which effectively `s1.toLowerCase().equals(s2.toLowerCase())`. Note that the comparator approach is not locale-sensitive whereas the toLowerCase() approach implicitly depends on the default locale. It's unclear whether this is significant for the OP, but it might give unexpected results.

Comment: If a case-insensitive and locale-specific approach is required, then a suitable `Collator` instance can be used as the TreeSet Comparator instead of String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER. This approach can't be used with toLowerCase() and HashSets. The TreeSet approach is probably slower than the HashSet approach, so it depends whether the OP is more concerned about flexible semantics or performance.

Comment: @Stuart Marks Indeed, there is this subtle difference that I didn't notice.  So yes `Collator` for specific Locale (that is not necessarily the default one) and  `Comparator.comparing(String::toLowerCase)` if the default locale suits.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no native library providing this, I think you'll always have to do some workaround, but the following could be an elegant solution without having to change your existing collections.

```
public boolean containsAllIgnoreCase(Collection<String> var1, Collection<String> var2) {
    return var1.stream()
               .map(String::toLowerCase)
               .collect(toList())
               .containsAll(var2.stream()
                                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                                .collect(toList());
}
```

Or even more easier to read

```
public List<String> toLowerCaseList(Collection<String> var) {
    return var.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).toList();
}

public boolean containsAllIgnoreCase(Collection<String> var1, Collection<String> var2) {
    return toLowerCaseList(var1).containsAll(toLowerCaseList(var2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If an implementation that works with `Set`s is enough, you could store your unique elements in a `TreeSet` with a special case-insensitive comparator:

```
Set<String> uniqueStrings = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

This way you can make the comparison simply with `uniqueStrings.equals(anotherTreeSet)`. It's a bit of a hack, I have to admit.